# Fix screen sizes in swift 2.0 migration

Tags: iphone, screen-size, swift2, xcode7

I recently migrated one of my projects to Swift 2.0 and all of a sudden I have huge black bars at the top and bottom of every iPhone except the 4s!

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add a launch image for the 4-inch screen.